# Linear functional as linear combination of others. (The weak topology does not come from a metric )

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

I am following a reading in french on weak topology and to prove that it does not come from any metric we have the following scheme:

Let be $X$ a Banach space with dim $X=\infty$.

-suppose it does. Let $d$ the metric

-for all $n\ge 1$, exists $\varepsilon_n>0$ and a finite $F_n\subset X^*$ such if $V_n=\{x\in X: |\varphi(x)|\leq \varepsilon_n, ~~\forall \varphi\in F_n\} $, then every neighborhood of 0 in the weak topology contains one $V_n$.

-Let be $Y_n$ the subspace generated by $F_n$, then exists $\varphi_0\in X^*$ such $\varphi_0\notin\bigcup_{n\ge1} Y_n$. (This is just Baire theorem)

-Show that $U=\{x\in X: |\varphi_0(x)|\leq 1\}$ does not contains any $V_n$.

In this last item, suppose it has some $V_n$, then exists some finite $F_n$ in $X^*$ and it is easy to prove, since ker$\varphi$ is a subspace, for all $\varphi\in X^*$, that $\bigcap_{\varphi\in F_n} ker\varphi\subseteq ker \varphi_0$.
The the book says that it implies $\varphi_0$ is a linear combination of elements of $F_n$. And this is the contradiction. This is the line that I do not understand.

why $\varphi_0\in Y_n$?.

Comment: que libro usas Luis Felipe?

Comment: Cours d'analyse fonctionnelle de Daniel Li

Comment: Exercise 19, chapter 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take the quotient space of X and the intersections with the kernels, this is a finite dimensional space (codimension of the intersection is less or equal than n).

The linear functionals are well defined on the quotient space and they separate points, so they will generate the dual quotient space.
By Kernel inclusion, the functional $\phi_0$ is well defined on the quotient space and as the functionals generate that space, it is a linear combination of them.